# Errors With Libgdx While Using Scala And Gradle

Tags: java, android, scala, gradle, libgdx

I am trying to configure scala in my libgdx project with the gradle build tool, as written in this article https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Using-libgdx-with-Scala.
I edited allproject and the core gradle files as written in the article. After that i changed my MyGdxGame class from java class to scala class. and after i tried to start the desktop laucher i got the error - Gradle : error : cannot find symbol class MyGdxGame. 
How can i solve this issue?

My core gradle file :

```
apply plugin : "java"
apply plugin : "scala"
sourceCompatibility = 1.6
[compileJava, compileTestJava]*.options*.encoding = 'UTF-8'

sourceSets.main.scala.srcDirs = [ "src/" ]
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ["src/"]
eclipse.project {
name = appName + "-core"
}
```

my allprojects gradle file :

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.2'
  }
}

allprojects {
apply plugin: "eclipse"
apply plugin: "idea"

version = '1.0'
ext {
    appName = "scalaTest"
    gdxVersion = '1.9.4'
    roboVMVersion = '2.2.0'
    box2DLightsVersion = '1.4'
    ashleyVersion = '1.7.0'
    aiVersion = '1.8.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
  }
}

project(":desktop") {
apply plugin: "java"

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
  }
  }

project(":android") {
apply plugin: "android"

configurations { natives }

dependencies {
    compile project(":core")
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
    natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
}
}

project(":core") {
apply plugin: "java"
apply plugin: "scala"

dependencies {
    compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
    compile "org.scala-lang:scala-library:2.11.7"
}
}

tasks.eclipse.doLast {
    delete ".project"
}
```

Comment: did you try to clean your project?

Comment: @WillEvers Yes I do. It doesn't help.

Comment: I don't see any reference of that class in these Gradle scripts, so you must have some reference of the java file in your code.

Comment: @WillEvers where exactly I have to reference this class?

Comment: Im not sure where you are referencing it. I would do a global search in your project and look for any references to the java file, which no longer exists.

Comment: @WillEvers I tried to create scala class in the directory of the DesktopLauncher. Scala classes are not found in the DesktopLauncher class.